# Forwarding all subdomains in one IP in a any Linux distro

Tags: linux-networking, internal-dns, dnsmasq

For a Rails application (using [Puma server](https://github.com/puma/puma)), we need to serve a list of subdomains ( e.g. users.example.test, admin.example.test and so on) all of which should point to localhost/127.0.0.1 (development environment)

I looked into `dnsmasq` but I wasn't successful in getting this to work. 
I also read that adding domain "wildcards" with `dnsmasq` is not straightforward.

concretely, I want to :

```
randomsubdomain.example.com -> 127.0.0.1
anotherrandomsubdomain.example.com -> 127.0.0.1
evenmorerandomsubdomain.example.com -> 127.0.0.1
```

(and it would be nice if the steps taken to achieve that could be automated / Dockerized ) (`puma-dev` is not considered)

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? This description is too vague to determine what you need.

Comment: added concrete example! sorry, I had a long unnecessary introduction... @MichaelHampton

Comment: Is this for a dev/test environment? You could just put them in the hosts file, as usual.

Comment: I guess the subdomain needs to be dynamic / its not fixed

Comment: Then automate the addition of the record in your hosts file every time someone creates a new subdomain or web application.

Comment: and that's the part where I need the answer for :) if you would like to post it I would gladly accept it!